# Lazily instantiate a rarely used a view model?

Tags: c#, .net, mvvm, viewmodel, lazy-initialization

My main view model (`mainViewModel`) contains an inner view model (`innerViewModel`) that is bound to it's view (innerView) using a DataTemplate.

In my `mainView` I have a `ContentPresenter` that has it's Content property bound to the `innerViewModel` and it's Visibility bound to an `IsVisible` property. The Visibility property is Collapsed and will very rarely be set to Visible.

My `mainViewModel` is one of ~1000 in a list. Currently each instance of `mainViewModel` also has an instance of `innerViewModel` that is almost never used. Is there a standard way of lazily instantiating the `innerViewModel` such that it is created only when it's view becomes visible? The normal approach of lazily instantiating does not work, since `innerViewModel` is used in a binding.

Perhaps there is a better approach to housing a rarely seen control within another one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Is there a standard way of lazily instantiating the innerViewModel such that it is created only when it's view becomes visible?"

The solution is to do just that. Now I don't actually create an instance of innerViewModel until the IsVisible property is first set to true. This means that the Content of the ContentPresenter on the mainView is bound to null for most of the time, but this does not seem to be a problem.

Comment: Seems hacky... What is to say that just because its not visible, various properties are not still being interacted with?

Answer (score 2):

Try using the [Lazy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997286.aspx) object for lazy initialization.